# How do I use Django's Related Lookups?

Tags: django, django-orm

I notice that Django's relational fields register 7 lookups:

```
fk.get_lookups()
    'in'        : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedIn'>,
    'exact'     : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedExact'>,
    'lt'        : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedLessThan'>,
    'gt'        : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedGreaterThan'>,
    'gte'       : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedGreaterThanOrEqual'>,
    'lte'       : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedLessThanOrEqual'>,
    'isnull'    : <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_lookups.RelatedIsNull'>}

defined    in https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py
registered in https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/models/fields/related.py
```

I'm familiar with how to use `__exact` (aka `=`), `__in`, and `__isnull` with relations, but there's no mention in the docs of what it means to apply lt / lte / gt / gte to a relation.  Are they set comparisons?

Comment: when apply ```lt / lte / gt / gte``` to a relation. It compare ```primary key ``` of related model

Answer (score 0):

- `__lt`: less than (get records that are less than a specific value) equivalent to `<`
- `__gt`: greater than (get records that are greater than a specific value) equivalent to `>`
- `__lte`: less than or equal to (get records that are less than, or equal to a specific value) equivalent to `=<`
- `__gte`: greater than or equal to (get records that are greater than, or equal to a specific value) equivalent to `=>`

**Example**:

`.filter(score__lt=100)` : objects with score less than 100.

*SQL equivalent*: `WHERE score < 3;`

`.filter(id__lte=3)` : objects with id less than or equal to 3.

*SQL equivalent*: `WHERE id <= 3;`

- You can also combine these lookups with the `F` function:

`.filter(rating__lt=F('number_of_comments')`

You can see more examples in [Django Docs](https://%22Field%20lookups%22%20%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#:%7E:text=for%20more%20details.-,Field%20lookups,-%C2%B6).

Comment: I don't mean for regular fields, I mean specifically for relation fields - those created by ForeignKey, OneToOneField, and ManyToManyField.